# Build gstreamer packages for Mendel Linux

Tags: linux, arm, google-coral, pbuilder

I am working on a project with a Coral Dev Board Mini which runs "Mendel Linux". When trying to set up a pipeline including webrtc with gstreamer, I found out that some gstreamer plugins are missing in the distribution (nice, webrtc). So I downloaded the source of the Mendel Linux distribution (instructions [here](https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md)) and tried to follow the instructions to (cross) compile it on my Ubuntu 20.04 X86 system.

After getting the source code I can run the system build with

```
m
```

which seems to work although in the output there are some errors of the type

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon: unable to open pidfile /dev/null (Permission denied)
E: pbuilder: Failed extracting the source
```

However, I need to build gstreamer which forms part of "packages". When I run

```
m packages
```

I get the following error:

```
cd /media/claus/extssd/dev/mendel/out/target/product/mt8167s_excelsior/obj/mendel-minimal; pdebuild --buildresult /media/claus/extssd/dev/mendel/out/target/product/mt8167s_excelsior/packages/core -- --debbuildopts "--build=full -sa --check-command=lintian --check-option=--profile=mendel" --basetgz /media/claus/extssd/dev/mendel/cache/cross-base.tgz --configfile /media/claus/extssd/dev/mendel/build/pbuilderrc --hookdir /media/claus/extssd/dev/mendel/build/pbuilder-hooks --host-arch arm64 --logfile /media/claus/extssd/dev/mendel/out/target/product/mt8167s_excelsior/mendel-minimal-arm64.log
cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99network-settings': Permission denied
E: /home/claus/.pbuilderrc could not be loaded
make: *** [/media/claus/extssd/dev/mendel/build/packages.mk:149: /media/claus/extssd/dev/mendel/out/target/product/mt8167s_excelsior/.mendel-minimal-pbuilder-arm64] Error 1
```

There seems to be some permission problem to create `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99network-settings` which should be in `/media/claus/extssd/dev/mendel/out/target/product/mt8167s_excelsior/obj/mendel-minimal`. I have

```
(base) claus$ ls -l etc/apt
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 claus claus 4096 Apr 14 22:26 apt.conf.d
```

which seems right to me, but `99network-settings` is not created in `apt.conf.d`. In my `/home/claus/.pbuilderrc` I have as content the following line:

```
cp ~/99network-settings /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
```

Any idea what might be going wrong here? I could not find more information than the linked "getting started" doc, there are some blog entries, but they seem to describe a previous version.

Comment: Did you try to build with super user permissions ?

Comment: Do you mean running the whole "m" build as root? I think pdebuild should take care of obtaining the root privilege? I'll give it a try..